# Function returning function doesnt work for redux form field-level validation.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, redux-form-validators

It`s a bit weird behavior, but I cannot actually figure out whats going on with my validation :)

I have a field level validation

```
export const confirm = (valueToConfirm, message) => (value, allValues) => {
  if (value !== allValues[valueToConfirm]) {
    return message;
  }

  return undefined;
};
```

And its using like

```
<Field
  type="email"
  name="confirmEmail"
  component={TextInput}
  validate={[required, email, confirm('email', 'Bla-bla-bla')]}
/>
```

And thats actually works only in case, when some another validation failed. So if user input correct all fields, and just confirmEmail would not match email - there **would not be any validation error!**

But if I change validation, so it would not be a function returning function - it works.

```
export const confirmEmail = (value, allValues) => {
  if (!value || value !== allValues.email) {
    return 'Bla-bla-bla';
  }

  return undefined;
};
```

P.S. Same for all Field-level validation, for example dynamic `minLength` validation.

Comment: In the question you use `confirm` and `confirmEmail`. Just to make sure, are you updating the function name in the `validate` array with the name change?

Comment: Thats just 2 funcs, 1st - doesnt work, second - works

Answer (score 0):

I know you are using Redux Field however this is also easily achievable with Vanilla React.

```
<form>
 <input
                type="text"
                name="username"
                placeholder="name"
                value={this.state.username}
                onChange={this.handleChange}/>
</form>

 handleChange(e) {
   //check for validation here to have real time feedback to user when their 
   inputs match what you're looking for. 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `confirm` validation function is incorrect. The validation function you're using:

```
export const confirm = (valueToConfirm, message) => (value, allValues) => {
  if (value !== allValues[valueToConfirm]) {
    return message;
  }

  return undefined;
};
```

with the arguments you're using:

```
confirm('email', 'Bla-bla-bla')
```

means it will *always* validate. You're validating the value of the `email` input against the value of the `email` property in `allValues`, which is the value the `email` input. That is:

```
// value = test@example.com
// allValues = {email: 'test@example.com'}
// valueToConfirm = 'email'
// message = 'Bla bla bla'

if (value !== allValues[valueToConfirm]) {
  return 'Bla bla bla';
}
```

which evaluates to:

```
if (test@example.com !== test@example.com) {
  return 'Bla bla bla';
}
```

this conditional will always fail, meaning the validation will pass.